# How to use @Body to pass data from android to asp.net Web service web method using retrofit

Tags: asp.net, .net, web-services, asp.net-web-api, retrofit

I am trying to send data from android to asp.net( web service web method) using Class object but "500 Internal server error" occurs. And If I pass data using @Query then data is transfer and insert the record successfully.

Is there any way to send data from android to asp.net using class object using @Body.